# FFMPEG Encode .avi/.mov with alpha channel to .3g2 (with alpha kept)

Tags: ffmpeg, converters, alpha

I'd like to convert my 32bits videos (either .avi or .mov) RGB+A, to .3g2 format with FFMPEG, and keep the alpha channel.

It should be something like that

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\naldo\Desktop\test.avi  -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -ab 48k -ar 22050 -ac 2 C:\Users\naldo\Desktop\test.alpha.3g2
```

but it's not working.
Any ideas ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

H.264, your chosen codec, does not support alpha. And neither does H.263, the default codec for 3GP.

**Edit**: Based on further info [given](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3226) at the support forum, and a reference [file](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/6e6b42bf05bd1a3194fe2a25a9274fb620161103081504/430f86), here's the answer for the alpha stacking method.

There's no alpha channel in the reference video. What's done there is the alpha stream is stacked with the image formed by the color channels and the handling app uses the 2nd half of the image to act as a compositing key.

To do this, use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex "[0]transpose=2,split[v][va];[va]alphaextract[a];[v][a]hstack" -c:v libx264 out.3g2
```

As per the reference file, the video is first rotated 90 deg CCW. Note that the reference uses H.263 and ffmpeg's encoder only supports certain preset sizes. There's no such restriction for H.264, which is used in my command.

To encode as per the settings in the command in the comments, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex "[0]transpose=2,split[v][va];[va]alphaextract[a];[v][a]hstack,scale=640x360,setdar=18/16" -c:v mpeg4 -vb 400k -r 20 -c:a aac -ar 22050 out.alpha.3g2
```

Comment: Hello, thanx for helping !
here are the comments 
"
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-filter_complex'

Previously, I'll need to mention .alpha for the outside. And for the AR software used after that.

Comment: One of my friend who did it previously me with me send me a .sh file that he recovers from our last folder's work.
Here is the last sentence :
"$FFMPEG_EXE_PATH" -i "$1" -vf "[orig] transpose=dir=2 [rotated]; [rotated] split [a][b]; [b] alphaextract [alphaAsGrayscale]; [alphaAsGrayscale] pad=iw*2:ih:iw:0 [alphaAsGrayscalePadded]; [alphaAsGrayscalePadded][a] overlay" -vcodec mpeg4 -s 640x360 -aspect $((HEIGHT*2)):$WIDTH -vb 400000 -r 20 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ar 22050 out.alpha.3g2

Comment: If you haven't made a typo, your ffmpeg is VERY old. Get a recent static build from [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: No change with the new build. Still not working. I'll try more and post you comment lines soon.

Comment: Hello,I had a new code from an app, but using their ffmpeg version
ffmpeg -i C:\convert-flv\01.avi  -vf "split[a][b]; [a]pad=iw:ih*2[src]; [b]format=rgba,alphaextract[filt]; [src][filt]overlay=0:h" C:\convert-flv\01_1.avi
It's working for an .avi.

But now, I cannot make it work for .3g2, or with another FFMPEG version.

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime supports alpha and also WebM.

```
ffmpeg -i image%04d.png output.webm
```

Comment: (Sorry for my english) The software that I will use after re-encoding, requires .3g2 format, exclusively. So I need to keep .3g2, but find another codec, is that correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the 3g2 format and alpha but maybe using a different codec or container will help. ffmpeg -i test.mpg  -acodec libfaac -ab 64k -ar 22050 -vcodec mpeg4 -s qcif -b 120k -r 30 out.3g2